# Is there a way to read dmesg.old with absolute timestamps

Tags: amazon-linux, dmesg

Is there a way, using `dmesg` or otherwise to see the data in `/var/log/dmesg.old` with an absolute timestamp? I'm trying to get the same effect as `dmesg -T` but on older data.
I'm using Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03. The `-F` option for opening a different file does not work with other options. I've tried `-T`, `-L`, `-e`, and probably a few more.
The dmesg version is "dmesg from util-linux 2.23.2".